# Python descriptors (__get__, __set__) on function parameters

Tags: python, function, parameters, decorator, descriptor

Normally a descriptor is used on a class attribute like so:

```
class Owner(object):
    attr = Attr()
```

When getting `Owner.attr`, `Attr.__get__(self, instance, owner)` is called where `self = Owner.attr`, `instance = None` and `owner = Owner`.

When `Owner` is instantiated `instance` will be the instance of `Owner`.

Now I would like to apply this concept to method parameters instead of class attributes.

How it would look in practice (let's assume that the functionality of `Attr` is to wrap a string with a given string):

```
class Example(object):
    def funct(self, param=Attr('t')):
        return param == 'test' # < param calls the descriptor here

e = Example()
e.funct('es') # < is True because 'es' wrapped with 't' becomes 'test'.
```

When accessing `param`, `Attr.__get__(self, instance, owner)` will be called with `self = funct.param`, `instance = funct` and `owner = funct` (although it doesn't make sense to have `owner` and `instance` the same, might be `None`?).
But since `funct` is not a class, this will not work. How can I get something similar to work?

A decorator on the function will be processing the parameters, so this might add to the solution I think.
The decorator must be, for example, be able to change the wrapper string.

Comment: Can you add a usage scenario showing how `param` would be accessed?

Comment: What's the purpose of this functionality?  Are you trying to attach state to the functions?  Are you trying to dynamically define the behavior of the function via arguments?  Are you trying to defer resolution of some dependency until the function is executed?

Comment: @unutbu I've added a usage example I think suits more. Do you think it's clearer now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions actually are first class objects in Python, but you are correct in saying that the syntax you describe would not work as you want.  You could potentially do something like this with a decorator that inspects the passed attributes for characteristics that would enable this sort of functionality though.  However, you'd probably be better off implementing a callable object, then attaching descriptors to that and creating instances of the callable rather than functions.

Comment: I've chosen a different way of solving the problem. However this approach will work. My decorators preserve 'signatures' of decorated objects, for a function this can be achieved by creating a callable class with the descriptor attributes and wrapping the function in the `__call__` method. The argspec of the original function can then be copied to the `__call__` method. NICE! side-note: it was a requirement that functions/methods were used, a plain callable class didn't suffice, but with the decorator it should be possible.